# Visual Studio 2010 Ult Auto Load Testing Auto Adding Test Data

Tags: visual-studio-2010, load-testing

I need to carry out Automated Load testing on a site and I need test data to be added as this load test is conducted.

Any ideas how I can achieve this through Visual Studio 2010 Ult.

Also when running coded UI tests, it fails when I open Wizards/Modals (i frames) any help with this please.

Answer (score 0):

Use can the [DeploymentItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.deploymentitemattribute%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) attribute for that.

1. Open the `Test View` window.
2. Search for your `Load Test`, right click on it and select properties.
3. In the `Properties` window click an the `Deployment Items` property and add you test data file's path. The path is project relative.

The file will be deployed inside the aseembly's output folder. So, inside your unit tests' or web performance tests' code you can refer to your test data file by using the assemby's location.